# $record not passing the value

Tags: php, return-value, upgrade, deprecated

Since migrating to PHP7.1, "$record" is no longer writing to the db.

It is still adding +1 record to the index but it does not write the actual information into the file namefile.dat.

namefile.dat permission is set to 644, but the file still returns empty, with no data.

```
if (!$db->open("../namefile"))    {
    $schema = array(
        array("key", FFDB_INT, "key"),
        array("nname", FFDB_STRING),
        array("desc", FFDB_STRING),
        array("daya", FFDB_INT),
        array("yeara", FFDB_INT)
        );
    // Try and create it...
    if (!$db->create("namefile", $schema))       {
        echo "Error creating database\n";
        return;
    }
}
$record["key"] = $data;
$record["nname"] = ucwords($datana);
$record["desc"] = $desc;
list($record["daya"]) = sscanf($daya, "%d"); // string -> int
list($record["yeara"]) = sscanf($yeara, "%d"); // string -> int
```

Any ideas? Because I tried changing to $_POST to force it....

```
   $record["key"] = $_POST[$data];
   $record["nname"] = ucwords($_POST["$datana"]);
   $record["desc"] = $_POST["$desc"];
   list($record["daya"]) = sscanf($_POST["$daya", "%d"]);
   list($record["yeara"]) = sscanf($_POST["$yeara", "%d"]);
```

....but still failing in writing the values to the file.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

EDITING

Error log is pointing to these 2 functions -

```
 function read_byte($fp)     {
    return $this->bin2dec(fread($fp, 1), 1);
 }


function read_str($fp)     {
    $strlen = $this->bin2dec(fread($fp, 4), 4);
    return fread($fp, $strlen);
 }
```

NOTE: bin2dec works as like bindec, no errors

Comment: Which version were you using before?

Comment: What is the class of `$db`?

Comment: Is this [Flat File Database](http://ffdb-php.sourceforge.net/docs/index.html)?

Comment: PHP5.6 and all was fine. BUT to do more damage to the situation I also migrated to a new server. Phpcodechecker.com is not accusing any errors with the original script

Comment: yes, flat file db....it works perfectly for my scenario

Comment: $db = new FFDB();

Comment: That code hasn't been updated in almost 6 years, it might not be compatible.

Comment: But it has worked until last week when I moved to a new server and they only had PHP7.1 available. And still php code checker is coming back clean. The only error parsing is                                                                                                    PHP Strict Standards:  Only variables should be passed by reference.....

Comment: Can you turn the code in the post into a [mcve] so we can try it?

Comment: This is what I was planning to do next "Minimal", try to write only 1 of the simplest one's field to see, but I am on a time crunch with this....I am updating above the show the lines where the error log is logging

Comment: You never call `$db->add($record)` to write the record to the database.

Comment: What is the error in the error log?

Comment: Since, it is writing to the index and it is writing to header of the flat file db, it says something about "passing the value". This is why I think that it can only be something how is writing the file

Comment: I posted above the lines with error.....but this is what the log says PHP Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference

Comment: it does  if (!$db->add($record))

Answer (score 0):

The `bin2dec` method is defined as:

```
function bin2dec(&$str, $len)
```

So the first parameter is declared to be a reference variable. This means that when you call it, the corresponding argument has to be a variable that can be updated. But it's being called like this:

```
  return $this->bin2dec(fread($fp, 4), 4);
```

You can't use a function call as the argument when the function parameter is a reference variable, since there's no variable for it to reference.

There's actually no reason why the first argument to `bin2dec()` needs to be a reference, since the function never modifies it. Change the function definition to:

```
function bin2dec($str, $len)
```

FFDB seems to have lots of unnecessary reference variables and function parameters. It's pretty old code (over 16 years old), maybe in earlier versions of PHP this was useful to prevent unnecessary copying. PHP has been using copy-on-write for many years now, so there's no need to use references for this purpose any more.

I edited `ffdb.inc.php` and replaced all `&$` with `$` except for:

```
function add(&$record)
```

This seems to be needed for `FFDB_INT_AUTOINC` columns, which are modified in place in `$record` when storing.

After doing this I didn't get any `Only variables should be passed by reference` errors.

Comment: It didn't do it, it tripled the number of errors. But then I notice that the error is actually on the functions of read_byte and read_str and NOT write_byte nor wirte_str - so it technically is just not writing to the file. And the error is coming back, I am guessing here, because it tries to read the file and index shows 1 but the db is empty.....am I making any sense? Well, I have to go, I am late for picking up my dad. Thank you Barmar. I won't mind if you come back tomorrow....I will try the minimal ;)

Comment: If it's just printing notices, the code should still work. I get a notice when I use a function call with a reference parameter, but a fatal error if I use a literal. FFDB doesn't use any literals that should cause a fatal error.

Comment: Hi Barmar, I made the changes, thanks. Unfortunately still nothing. Actually, no errors are outputting after replacing &$ with $, but the values are still not passing. I did minimal, 1 single field, the most basic one and still not passing. So I just opened a trouble ticket to check the server, perhaps somewhere is not permitting the file to be written and bypassing my 644 permission. I even tried changing to 666 but still nothing, I will keep you posted with the trouble ticket I opened. Thank you again Barmar!

Comment: Are you calling `$db->add()` after you update `$record`? Nothing automatically writes to the database when you just modify the variable.

Comment: Using this flat 4 4ever, and its all in the same place as before when worked. But having said, during the minimal test I placed 2 echos - before and after - and it is echoing in the screen perfectly, only not writing to the file. Also, the script has an echo if (!$db->add($record)) echo("failed!\n"); to notify for an error if the record is not written as default, and echo is NOT echoing at all. Again, it validates my theory that the script is acting as if it is adding, since is adding +1 to the index, but in reality is not writing because something is preventing from writing to that file.

Comment: That's the call to `$db->add()` that I was asking about.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem here. When I called `$db->add($record);` the file was updated.

Comment: The code that writes the record to the file seems very straightforward, I don't see anything that would be dependent on the PHP version.

Comment: That's what I think, and cpanel is tricky sometimes. I will keep you posted about the trouble ticket. Thank YOU again, please keep coming back ;)

Comment: Barmar, nothing with cpanel...I made lots of changes and the errors keep pilling up and getting worst because it stopped from writing on the 3 files, as originally I had writing in 2 but skipping one. I am stuck, do you work for yourself? do you take such tasks/projects of debugging / fixing other people's scripts?

Comment: Sorry, answering on SO is just a hobby in my spare time, I don't do consulting.

Comment: You can find people on the Stack Overflow Jobs site.